# how to generate unique sequence numbers to replace null values in a column of a table in spark scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am facing difficulty in generating unique sequence numbers to replace the null values in a column of a table. The table is obtained after joining two other tables and the column id the primary key column where null values are to be replaced with unique sequence values. 
I tried using accumulators but i am facing difficulty when running the program in a multinode cluster.

```
val joined=csv2.join(csv,csv2("ACCT_PRDCT_CD")===csv("ACCT_PRDCT_CD"),"left_outer")

joined.filter("ACCT_CO_NO is null").show

val k=joined.withColumn("Acc_flag", when($"ACCT_CO_NO".isNull,0).otherwise($"ACCT_CO_NO"))

var a=1

def generate(s:Int):Int={
   if (s==0){
             a=a+1
             return a
            }
   else     {
             return s
            }
   }

val generateNum = udf(generate(_:Int))

val newjoined=k.withColumn("n",generateNum($"ACC_flag"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, consider using [monotonically_increasing_id](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@monotonically_increasing_id():org.apache.spark.sql.Column) or RDD's [zipWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@zipWithIndex():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T,Long)]).  To avoid collision, the generated sequence numbers will then be added to a number greater than the maximum column value before replacing the `null`s.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dfL = Seq(
  (1, "a"),
  (2, "b"),
  (3, "c"),
  (4, "d"),
  (5, "e"),
  (6, "f")
).toDF("c1", "c2")

val dfR = Seq(
  (1, 100L),
  (2, 200L),
  (3, 300L)
).toDF("c1", "c2")

val c2max = dfR.select(max($"c2")).first.getLong(0)
// c2max: Long = 300

val dfJoined = dfL.join(dfR, Seq("c1"), "left").
  select(dfL("c1"), dfR("c2"))
```

**METHOD 1**: using `monotonically_increasing_id`

```
dfJoined.withColumn( "c2x", when(col("c2").isNotNull, col("c2")).
    otherwise(monotonically_increasing_id + c2max + 1)
  ).
  show
// +---+----+-----------+
// | c1|  c2|        c2x|
// +---+----+-----------+
// |  1| 100|        100|
// |  2| 200|        200|
// |  3| 300|        300|
// |  4|null|25769804077|
// |  5|null|34359738669|
// |  6|null|42949673261|
// +---+----+-----------+
```

Note that the generated sequence numbers aren't necessarily consecutive.

**METHOD 2**: using RDD's `zipWithIndex`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val rdd = dfJoined.rdd.zipWithIndex.
  map{ case (row: Row, idx: Long) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ idx) }

spark.createDataFrame(rdd,
    StructType(dfJoined.schema.fields :+ StructField("idx", LongType))
  ).
  select( $"c1", $"c2",
    when(col("c2").isNotNull, col("c2")).otherwise($"idx" + c2max + 1).
      as("c2x")
  ).
  show
// +---+----+---+
// | c1|  c2|c2x|
// +---+----+---+
// |  1| 100|100|
// |  2| 200|200|
// |  3| 300|300|
// |  4|null|304|
// |  5|null|305|
// |  6|null|306|
// +---+----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks Leo for answering the question.

Comment: My requirement specifically requires generating sequential unique values not some random values. I used accumulator for incrementing an initial value and the output obtained is an erratic value not a sequence, your suggestion is appreciated.I used the below code              var uniqueID = 6000001
 var a = sc.accumulator(uniqueID)

 def generate(s:Int):Int = {
  
  if (s==0)
  {
   a = a.add(1)
   return a.localValue
  }
  else
  {
   return s
  }
 
 val genNum = udf(generate(_:Int))
 val KeyGen = table_n.withColumn("Key_New", genNum(table_n("record_status")))

Comment: I found this formula in an ETL tool but unable to implement the same in Spark.  (next_in_sequence() * number_of_partitions() + this_partition()+1 -number_of_partitions())+${maximum sequence number} your suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I wonder one thing: monotonically_increasing_id probably does not make sure that the values it generates won't collide with the existing values in col("val")?

Comment: @Frank, you're right.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Even though it isn't explicitly stated in the question, it's probably part of the requirement.  Answer revised.

Comment: @RSG, my apologies for not following up your comments. Anyway, I updated the solution to include two different ways of creating unique sequence numbers.

Comment: I have/had more or less same problem as the original poster (replace nulls in a column that is basically some index), that's why I came across this :). I did not solve it yet, I may end up writing some UDF with a method that will fetch a unique sequence from e.g. a RDBMS. Might hurt performance (a lot?), but all solutions which only use Spark don't convince me yet. E.g. with the "max approach", how soon might it run out of numbers when running the algorithm again and again, e.g. when adding new data.

Comment: @Frank, regularly re-assigning `null`s with unique sequence numbers for a column doesn't sound like a common use case.  In any case, I'm not sure a UDF that makes a database call for a unique sequence number would ever perform well with a large dataset, as UDF works in a row-by-row fashion and database call can be expensive.  I'm also not aware of any other methods more efficient than the ones described in the solution for filling a column with unique sequence numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I have a case where I need to split up incoming records into multiple records and then issue new IDs for those new records (basically part of a ETL pipeline). And then merge this with an existing dataframe, which ran through Apache Spark before. Anyway, I've thought about it and maybe some UUID-based approach is good enough (generate a long UUID based on time ), e.g. https://ivanyu.me/blog/2015/10/25/retrospective-time-based-uuid-generation-with-spark/. So that collisions are very very unlikely. I'll see :)